# Javascript slider with larger center slide? < [ small BIG small] >

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

What I am trying to accomplish is having a slider that has a large center slide and then on either side they shrink into the background. I've seen this before on websites but the best example I can find is:

http://www.jcoverflip.com/demo

Unfortunately that one doesn't look like a great solution.

I decided to try and use this example from bxslider, but I'm unsure if there is a way to tell what slide is centered to the viewer: http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-demystified#example4

So what I would like is something that I can use, or a way to get this effect going. Or even what the effect is called so I can reliably search for it?

Comment: That first slider works fine for me in Firefox 21.0 and Safari 5.1.9. Neither browser shows any errors in the console.

Comment: Yeah, I figured out that it requires jquery UI as well, but I don't even need the jquery UI functionality implemented in the slider (and that part is poorly executed anyways).

Comment: I believe the effect is called 'coverflow'

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on a small DOM library called pocketknife that also has a range slider extension (no true demo up atm, but the test suite ends on one, http://pomax.github.io/pocketknife/test.html) for which you can modify the look of the slider using plain CSS, which lets you use an `onchange` event handler to do whatever you need done... I'm stilled working on the documentation but the code's on github if you want to give that a try.

(I use it myself on http://pomax.github.io/mathparser/, for instance)

Answer (score 0):

My advice: write a great one from scratch and make it free.

AKA Fliptych http://thetreehouseandthecave.blogspot.com/2006/08/fliptych-interface.